# Installation of Monero on Linux

Tags: linux, installation

I have downloaded the tarball and extracted the contents, now how do I install this in Linux?

Answer (score 3):

After extracting, you can either run the binaries directly from where you extracted them, or copy/move them to some other location (such as `/usr/local/bin`). Where you choose to install (i.e. copy/move), them is really up to you as the admin/user of your Linux box.

A nice overview of the binaries can be found at: https://monerodocs.org/interacting/overview/

Comment: MoneroDocs.org is sadly no longer available; please use https://getmonero.dev/docs/interacting/overview.html

Answer (score 0):

Download latest release: https://web.getmonero.org/downloads/

With [Dolphin](https://kde.org/applications/en/system/org.kde.dolphin) (Popular file manager):

[image: Image showing right click options]

Right click the .tar.bz2 and click Extract -> Extract archive here

[image: Screenshot of folder]

Find a new folder called monero-gui-v0.XX.X

[image: Image of monero-wallet-gui binary]

Open it, and double-click `monero-wallet-gui`. You're done!